# How can I add file version detail on properties to a .jar?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar

I'm looking to add a product version number to appear in my .jar file information. Currently I'm using Maven in my Spring boot project for API Rest.

I have read a lot of solutions about the manifest versioning. There you have to decompress and access to the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF to check the Implementation-Version. That's too tedious for what I'm looking for.

Like for a .exe. where you can found it under right mouse click -> details -> "product version" or simply checking on File Version column as shown on image. [Example of a file version description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZTlu.png).

Also I read that JAR file is a file format based on the popular ZIP file format and is used for aggregating many files into one. Kinda that I'm looking to add a file version to .zip, but I want to ask anyway if that is possible.

Regards, Gaspar.

Comment: Hi @user16320675, that is not what I'm looking for. From what I understand that will return me the implementationVersion but please take a look on attached image. Also, have you tryed what you suggest? Is not a solution for my issue but also doesn't work me, but anyway I tried on my void main and doesn't work. Regards, Gaspar.

Comment: @user16320675 Yes, is a Windows explorer image. I specifically detail in my question what is what I'm looking for: find the product version under right mouse click -> details -> "product version" like in a .exe. Anyway, I don't have in my project a MANIFEST.MF, it generates automatically when I do a "package" of my project afterwards.

Comment: @user16320675 However, accesing to the Implementation-Version on MANIFEST.MF on code it will not turn to a solution to me because I already have it on my pom.xml. I want a easy access version check of my .jar and it could not be on the name of the .jar itself, I don't know if I explain me correctly. Sorry if my previous answer seemed rude, English is not my main language and I try my best. Regards, Gaspar.

Answer (score 1):

A JAR file itself can't have a version. But you're using Maven, and that means you can already access the Maven version:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/<groupId>/<artifactId>/pom.properties")) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(inputStream);
    // available properties:
    // - artifactId=xxx
    // - groupId=xxx
    // - version=xxx
}
```

Note that this often doesn't work in unit tests (especially when run from IDEs) because the files are only added to the JAR file.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your answer. This still not help me about what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just include a text file anywhere in your jar. Build systems of all stripes make this trivial. Then write in your code that you read out this text file with the version, and show it on screen.

In maven, gradle, etc, to include a plain text file in the jar, just put it in `src/main/resources/version.txt` and it gets included automatically.

To read it in java:

```
public class Main {
  public static String getVersion() {
    try (var in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/version.txt")) {
      return new String(in.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
  }
}
```

This:

- Asks the classloader to load version.txt using the same systems that load `.class` files.
- reads that inputstream fully, and turns it into a string using the UTF_8 encoding.
- Uses try-with-resources because, it's a resource, you have to do that if you don't want leaks.

Comment: Yea, but from what I understand I will still have to access inside of the .jar in order to check the .jar version. Also I forgot to mention that my .jar filename have to remain exactly the same so the service that runs the .jar has no problems. As I said, it is an API Rest .jar that runs in background, I do not have and should not show anything on "screen" about the version in addition to what is shown in the attached image

Comment: Also I'm trying to do that and I'm getting the error "Cannot return a value from a method with void result type". Where should I do that, on my only void main?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessarily need the exact version, a mnemonic strategy I've seen is to touch the file timestamp. It may not be suitable and/or you'll have to determine what to do for numbers that fall outside the scope of a timestamp.

eg Use Powershell to set the LastWriteTime (or CreationTime) to match v2.3.4 -> 02:03:04

```
$ff = Get-Item my.jar
$ff.LastWriteTime         # Monday, 24 April 2023 16:25:56
$ff.LastWriteTime = $(Get-Date "24-apr-2023 02:03:04")
$ff.LastWriteTime         # Monday, 24 April 2023 02:03:04
```

LastWriteTime will show up in the "Date Modified" column of Windows Explorer.